# Java 8 kerberos constrained delegation

Tags: java-8, kerberos

Is there any example on how to do constrained delegation with Java 8/7. I tried searching around with no luck

Best Regards

Comment: I've summarized all the necessary details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377671/1471779

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java 8 code snippet that allows to generate a SPNEGO token with TGS ticket for an impersonated user:

```
GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
GSSName userName = manager.createName("targetUser", GSSName.NT_USER_NAME);
GSSCredential impersonatedUserCreds =
  ((ExtendedGSSCredential)serviceCredentials).impersonate(userName);

final Oid KRB5_PRINCIPAL_OID = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.1");
GSSName servicePrincipal =
  manager.createName("HTTP/webservice-host.domain.ltd", KRB5_PRINCIPAL_OID);
ExtendedGSSContext extendedContext =
  (ExtendedGSSContext) manager.createContext(servicePrincipal,
                                             new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.2"),
                                             impersonatedUserCreds,
                                             GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
final byte[] token = extendedContext.initSecContext(new byte[0], 0, 0);
```

Beware `extendedContext` is not established yet. Multiple rounds with server may be required.

A simple demonstration code is available at https://github.com/ymartin59/java-kerberos-sfudemo

You may also refer to the follow project code: https://github.com/tellisnz/collared-kerberos

Comment: I am getting - KDC cannot accommodate requested option (13)

any idea?

Comment: It works only when protocol transition is allowed. Fails when "Use kerberos only" option is selected.

Comment: That is expected. The ActiveDirectory option "Use kerberos only" concerns "Kerberos V5 delegation" where end-user TGT is flagged as forwardable - which may lead to security issues. That is exactly the point of Kerberos Constraint Delegation creation where end-user TGT no longer needs to be forwardable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sfu/bde93b0e-f3c9-4ddf-9f44-e1453be7af5a

Comment: So to sumup, "Use kerberos only" option does not allow Kerberos Constraint Delegation where ActiveDirectory expects you list all resources the service is expected to request TGS for.

Comment: I am talking about the case of constrained delegation only. Under "Trust this user for delegation to specified service only", you can see two options. "Use Kerberos Only" and "Use any authentication protocol" (aka protocol transition)
Your solution works for protocol transition only. For "Kerberos Only" setting, you need to get TGS for another service using user's TGS for current service. That is not covered in the sample code.

Comment: Correct, sample code does two steps: impersonation and then "delegation". If code has already received Kerberos/SPNEGO context in JAAS Subject, second step may work as-is. Again "Use Kerberos only" requires user TGT to be forwardable (as Kerberos V5 delegation) which has security risks. Kerberos Constrained Delegation requires to specify target SPN in "Trust this computer for delegation to specified services only" to allow trusted service account to request new TGS from received user's TGS. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc739740(v=ws.10)

Comment: "If code has already received Kerberos/SPNEGO context in JAAS Subject, second step may work as-is" --> 
Do you mean instead of obtaining impersonated credentials, i should directly call for get service ticket for service 2?

Comment: Exactly. With only service1-TGS in context (when end-user TGT is not forwarded), Java Kerberos stack should trigger S4U2Proxy (aka Constrained Delegation) to obtain "service2-TGS" as far as "service2" SPN is allowed in service1 account (section Trust this computer for delegation to specified services only)

Comment: Here is what i've done - 0) Constrained delegation with "Kerberos only" is set  (1) Perform Login using service 1 credentials (2) Accept kerberos ticket from user using "service1context.acceptSecContext" (3) Then we are trying to get TGS for service 2 using "service1Context.initSecContext" (4) What is received is TGS of service 2 for service1user instead of end user....  It will be really helpful if you can provide any sample code or pointers where i can get the sample code.

Comment: I am struggling on point #6 of figure 2 in following link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sfu/1fb9caca-449f-4183-8f7a-1a5fc7e7290a

Comment: OK. I made mistakes because Active Directory has two "Kerberos only" options (https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/4494313/configuring-web-enrollment-proxy-for-s4u2proxy-constrained-delegation). For an double-hop example you describe, I recommend to refer to https://github.com/tellisnz/collared-kerberos

Comment: Finally got the success !!
I've summarized here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377671/1471779