# What is the Purpose of "isInitiator" flag in Krb5LoginModule?

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas, gssapi, kerberos-delegation

I am working on Kerberos delegation, where I wish to impersonate the user based on incoming ticket, and make the connection to third party system.

My observation is, `context.getCredDelegState()` returns true only when `isInitiator` flag from the Krb5LoginModule settings is set to true.

My confusion is, my server side code (which is making connection on user's behalf) is *Acceptor* and not the *Initiator*, so isn't it obvious that I set the flag to false?
But then I am not able to delegate the credentials.

It will be really helpful if anyone can provide a good explanation.

UPDATE:
I figured out that when you set the delegation on for a service user in AD (say - "Trust this user for delegation to any service") - then the client (user who is accessing the service from browser) must log out and relogin. Then the delegated credentials are received. "isInitiator" is set to true in this case.

Comment: This should not be. You should enable JGSS debugging and look at Wireshark dump. Is the account trusted for delegation?

Comment: Surprisingly, it is happening irrespective of whether the account is enabled for delegation or not. I am definitely sure that context.getCredDelegState() works only if  isInitiator is set to true. The same thing is mentioned here also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743700/java-spnego-authentication-kerberos-constrained-delegation-kcd-to-backend-se/39779859#comment99086049_39779859

Comment: @BhushanKarmarkar After reviewing your comments in multiple questions, I wonder what you expect to achieve with Kerberos. Is "incoming ticket" a kerberos TGT ticket? Is that ticket forwardable? Why impersonation would be required in your context then? A diagram about your system authentication chain would be helpful to understand and help you... And probably yes, your code may be both acceptor (receive TGS ticket) and initiator (get another TGT for user if received one is not forwardable already)

Comment: @Michael-O I updated the question details.

Comment: @YvesMartin -check out the second diagram here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sfu/1fb9caca-449f-4183-8f7a-1a5fc7e7290a
I am trying to impersonate the user with a service account. Constrained delegation is set to the service user. My problem is, I can get the TGS for service 2 for user using TGT of my service user (impersonate, S4U2Self). However, as that link mentions, S4U2Proxy requires user's TGS, then only service user can get TGS for service 2 on user's behalf.
I am stuck there.