# WebLogic and Kerberos tickets in Java web apps

Tags: java, weblogic, kerberos

I'm not trying to configure and/or set up WL/Kerb, that's already set up and working fine.

What I can't find is an example of just getting the current Kerberos token from WebLogic in a web app.  Theoretically, it's already connected/authenticated to the KDC because the krb5.ini and JAAS login config are specified at startup time.  But, all the examples for Kerberos integration show the whole step of starting off with creating a LoginContext and passing credentials.  Shouldn't it already be logged in?  I don't need to create a new context, just get the existing context from WL somehow.  Struggling to find an example of this.

Comment: what is the exact use case? I didn't get it - why WL is authenticating here using Kerberos? Usually the end user who is accessing the webapp deployed on WL will be authenticated.

Comment: AD connection requires authentication so that pre-auth is supplied by a keytab.   Use case is User connects to service A, which needs to execute a web request on service B (in the same WebLogic server).

Comment: have you considered delegation? I've summarized delegation related code snippets here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743700/java-spnego-authentication-kerberos-constrained-delegation-kcd-to-backend-se/57377671#57377671