# Kerberos How To Delegate On Behalf Of Users AND Access Resources Independent Of Users

Tags: kerberos, kestrel-http-server, kerberos-delegation

I have a webapp running on Linux that uses Delegation to effectively mirror the permissions of the User that makes requests.  The webapp uses a keytab that looks something like this:

```
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   3 12/31/69 18:00:00 HTTP/my-website.com@DOMAIN
```

And the appropriate SPN is added to the webapp's service account, which looks something like this:

```
HTTP/my-website.com@DOMAIN
```

This all works fine.

There is a new requirement for the webapp to also be able to access resources it needs independent from the Delegation it does on behalf of users.  For example, there are databases it needs to access that users of the app don't necessarily have access to.  Is there a way for the webapp to use the same Keytab to generate tickets such that it can both continue to delegate on behalf of users AND access the resources it requires?

Comment: I've summarized delegation related code snippets here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743700/java-spnego-authentication-kerberos-constrained-delegation-kcd-to-backend-se/57377671#57377671

Comment: You did a nice job explaining different cases, but I don’t know if you covered this specific case. This specific case is the webapp needs to access databases independent of delegation AND it needs to access resources via delegation. How can I do both with a single keytab file?

Comment: If user doesn't have access to the resource, then it is not possible to access it using any mechanisms. End system will always deny the accecss.

Comment: 1) I assume there is a db system which will be accessed every time irrespective of which user is logging into your system. A dedicated common system account can be used. -> Answer is Yes, you can do it using a single keytab. Attach the SPN of your DBMS to a service account. Generate keytab. In JAAS config, make sure to set "isInitiator" flag to true.

Comment: 2) Assuming a user has access to a resource -> accessing resource on user's behalf then the constrained delegation (optionally with protocol transition) is the way to go. Which i explained in my another answer.